# Compare strings with regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to compare a String in combination with regex.
For instance:

```
return path == "/blog/2";
```

How can I replace the last part of the URL (the digit) with regex?
I want an exact match of the first part (blog) and a digit match for the last part (for instance: /blog/1, /blog/49, /blog/20913 are possible combinations).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\d+` or `[0-9]+` for the digits:

```
/\/blog\/\d+/.test(path)
```

If you want to match the whole string, then use anchor `^` and `$`

```
/^\/blog\/\d+$/.test(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I tried it as follows: 
`var reg = new RegExp('/\/blog\/\d+/');
return reg.test("/blog/22");` but I get "false". Why?

Comment: IF you use `RegExp` then you don't need the delimiter `/`. So it should be `RegExp('\/blog\/\d+');`

Answer (score 0):

You could  replace the last part by

```
 path.replace(/(\/blog)\/\d+/, '$1/replacement value')
```

See it in action & explanation: http://regex101.com/r/vR1pB7

```
/(\/blog)\/\d+/
    1st Capturing group (\/blog)
        \/ matches the character / literally
        blog matches the characters blog literally (case sensitive)
    \/ matches the character / literally
    \d+ match a digit [0-9]
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
```